# Capture as variable after NA calculation

Tags: r, dplyr

Using dplyr, tidyr, I want to create a new variable with the calculated values of the missing values.

Example:

```
data <- data.frame (c1 = 1:8, c2 = factor (c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c", "a", "b")))
data[4,1] <- data[6,2] <- NA
```

I calculate the % of NA like so but I would like to capture this with a mutate as well. I can't seem to get it right:

```
data %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean(is.na(.))))
```

I could do this:

```
data2 <- data %>%
      summarise_all(funs(Mean = mean(is.na(.))))
```

But I would prefer to have a "Mean" column. Desired output would be :

```
Var Mean
c1  %
c2  %
```

Comment: Can you show the full result that you would like for this input? If you have a `Mean` column, I'm not sure what value you want on each row. For example, your first row has `c1 = 1` and `c2 = 'a'`. What value for the `Mean` column do you want there?

Comment: Actually, c1 and c2 no longer matter after, so a new table could be created with the row names and one new variable: MeanNA

Comment: So, it doesn't sound like you want `mutate`, which is used to add columns to an existing data frame. But I still don't see your desired output, so I still don't know what you want... do you want any *other* columns than a `Mean` column? Or do you just want to turn the output you have into a vector? Do you want to change it from wide to long format?

Comment: Im just calculating the % of missing value for every variable, then I guess I want to gather them in a column and have the mean in another.

Comment: So... `%>% gather()`? **This would be very clear if you would edit your question to show your desired output for the input you provide.** Then I could stop asking questions in comments and start writing an answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't know why it wasn't working when I tried but your comment made me try again and it works with just adding gather() to the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
data <- data.frame (c1 = 1:8, c2 = factor (c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c", "a", "b")))
data[4,1] <- data[6,2] <- NA 

data
test<- data %>% summarise_all(funs(mean(is.na(.)))) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
names(test) <- "MeanNA"
test
```

which gives:

```
   MeanNA
c1  0.125
c2  0.125
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting but I was looking for a complete dplyr/tidyr solution. I found that adding gather works.

Comment: I saw that. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

After a discussion with Gregor, gather() worked when I tried it:

```
data2 <- data %>%
  summarise_all(funs(Mean = mean(is.na(.)))) %>%
  gather(key, value)
```

as akaDrHouse pointed out: gather(Var, meanNA) to rename the final columns.

Comment: Change gather to gather(Var,MeanNA)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using base R is

```
colMeans(is.na(data))
   c1    c2 
0.125 0.125
```

which produces a named vector. `is.na(data)` produces a logical matrix where TRUEs are observed when the element is NA. `colMeans` calculates the proportion of TRUE elements in each column.

To put this into a data.frame, use

```
data.frame(Mean=colMeans(is.na(data)))
    Mean
c1 0.125
c2 0.125
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(is.na(x)))], 
            variable.name = "Var", value.name = "MeanNA")   
#    Var MeanNA
#1:  c1  0.125
#2:  c2  0.125
```